# SQL Query to find matching Regex pattern for a given string

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a table which stores Regex patterns for barcodes. I need to find a row with regex which corresponds to given barcode. For example, if the barcode is `000912345`, the query should return row with Id 1 from table below.

| id | barcode_regex | source_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ^(00)09[0-9]{5}$ | 1 |
| 2 | ^(00)09[0-9]{16}$ | 2 |

Is this possible without iterating over the rows?

Comment: Good luck - SQL Server is very bad at handling regex. You might want to implement a CLR function, but I think any solution is going to be slow unless you can manage to exclude some rows quickly.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support regex in T-SQL script. You'd need to use SQL CLR-based functions or procedures to handle them in .NET code.

Comment: Whilst you may not use regex you may consider using like instead. i.e. you could have `WHERE '000912345' LIKE barcode_like_pattern`. If you could consider having both `barcode_regex` and `barcode_like_pattern` where the SQL Server does the first pass filtering based on `barcode_like_pattern` and you can have your application do a second pass filter on the regex, but, it has to be done in the application level not in SQL.

Comment: @StephenQuan I am open to add new column and filter application level as well. What do you mean by `barcode_like_pattern`? Can you given an example please?

Comment: For regex `^(00)09[0-9]{5}$` you could pre-filter results with something like `LIKE '0009%'` or `LIKE '0009_____'` and then apply the original regex, or you could filter directly with an equivalent `LIKE '0009[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`. Note that SQL Server patterns are very limited as defined in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#pattern-match-using-like). You might find that most or all of your relatively simple barcode regexes can be converted, but there are many regex features that do not translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample `TableT`:

| id | barcode_regex | barcode_like | source_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ^(00)09[0-9]{5}$ | 0009_____ | 1 |
| 2 | ^(00)09[0-9]{16}$ | 0009________________ | 2 |

Here's a sample DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TableT (id INTEGER, barcode_regex VARCHAR(100), barcode_like VARCHAR (100), source_id INTEGER);
INSERT INTO TableT VALUES (1, '^(00)09[0-9]{5}$', '0009_____', 1);
INSERT INTO TableT Values (2, '^(00)09[0-9]{16}$', '0009________________', 2);
```

Here's the corresponding SQL Query:

```sql
SELECT id, barcode_regex, source_id
FROM   TableT
WHERE  '000912345' LIKE barcode_like;
```

This will do a shortlist based on `barcode_like` for which you will have to do a second pass filter based on `barcode_regex` in your application to remove any false positives.

Comment: Instead of `_` to match "any character" can use `[0-9]` and an appropriate collate clause (e.g. Latin1_General_100_BIN) to match only 0123456789. Meaning no "false positives" or need for any regex check

Comment: @MartinSmith your suggestion is a good one because the OP clearly tagged sql-server. I was aware of it, but, choose not to use it since I wanted to keep the answer generic SQL. Whilst, sql-server your like pattern will eliminate the false positives in this case, but if we were to generalize, that optional may not always be available, so, there will always be scenarios where we want to deal with the false positives.

Comment: This works. as per @MartinSmith's suggestion, I changed `_`s to `[0-9]`.

Comment: @MartinSmith Or without a `COLLATE` you can do `[0123456789]`

Comment: @Charlieface - You would still likely want to control the collation with that https://dbfiddle.uk/vBTO2EGM